# Java Inconvertible types not detected

Tags: java, java-8

I came across this error today.

I am wondering why the compiler is able to generate an error in one case but not in the other that seems the same to me

I am not able to reproduce my real use case that is a bit more complex but I manage to demonstrate the error on a minimal weirder case

```
class JavaInconvertibleTypeBug {

    public interface HasInterface {

    }
    public static class A {

    }



    public void myFunc(HasInterface hasInterface) {

        if (hasInterface instanceof Integer) { //Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'JavaInconvertibleTypeBug.HasInterface' to 'java.lang.Integer'

        }

        if (hasInterface instanceof A) { //NO Error ? Why ?

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: make `A` `final` (just like `Integer` is) and you will find out why

Comment: My guess: `Integer` is a `final class` that does not implement `HasInterface`. Hence, an `HasInterface` can never be `instanceOf Integer`. Class `A` - on the other hand - is not `final`. Thus, theoretically there could exist a sub-class of `A` that `implements HasInterface` and the expression could evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be *another* class `B`, that `extends A` and `implements HasInterface`; compiler can't know that.

`java.lang.Integer` is `final`, so such a class can not exit, thus the error.

Make `A` `final` and you will get the same error.